# tab bar in all activities in an android app

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I need to add a tab bar in all activities and i have added in xml part by using
 in all the activities. I am struck at the coding part in java .Should I write code for this in every activity in java. Or is there any another way for doing this.

Comment: Look at this guide for more info.[Android TabLayout.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#CommonLayouts)

Answer (score 0):

If you're implementing for Android 3.2 and above I suggest using the action bar. If you're implementing for an android version below 3.2 use action bar sherlock (you can download it from the internet and include it in your application)